# Convert VMware VM to Virtual PC in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, conversion, vmware-player, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have an existing virtual machine which runs fine in VMware Player under Windows 7 until I attempt to run something else in Virtual PC.  Is there a way to easily convert my existing virtual machine over from VMware to VPC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice post describing steps involved in [converting VMWare's VMDK into VirtualPC's VHD](http://blog.brawney.com/2009/01/convert-vmware-vmdk-to-virtual-pc-vhd.html).
Excerpt:

> I ran across WinImage. Its a really nice tool. This product is not free; its shareware. One of the many things this product will do is actually convert a VMDK directly to a VHD.

Answer (score 2):

You can try StarWind V2V, which is completely free. Easy, quick and direct conversion from VMDK to VHD. I explained the steps clearly here,  http://www.sysprobs.com/convert-vmware-virtual-pc-2007-vmdk-vhd-starwind

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=42497), which claims to support this process.

Description from the website:

> The Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter provides a
>   Microsoft-supported, freely available, stand-alone solution for
>   converting VMware-based virtual machines and virtual disks to
>   Hyper-V-based virtual machines and virtual hard disks (VHDs)—including
>   conversion from VMware to Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

well your SO inside the VM is still an SO, you can try this.

grab an disk cloning software make an image out of the pc by using a live cd in the virtual machine.

then in the virtual pc software restore it. make sure your hardware is compatible tho.

I've successfully donde this with Acronis backup and restore, all though you need to pay for it.

here's a list of disk cloning software from wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_cloning_software

Comment: +1 I've just (this minute) used Symantec Ghost to ghost from VirtualBox to Virtual PC.